# Can anyone help me how to save multiple checkbox data in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have little information in making a laravel system. My question is how to store the Checked checkbox value into my database. I can't seem to figure this out.

```
<div class="controls">
    <td>
        <label class="checkbox inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="illness" value="cbx_aids">
            Aids
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label class="checkbox inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="illness" value="cbx_anemia">
            Anemia
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label class="checkbox inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="illness" value="cbx_arthritis">
            Arthritis
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label class="checkbox inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="illness" value="cbx_Artificial">
            Artificial Joints
        </label>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding `name = illness[]` instead of `name = illness` to get all the selected checkbox value.

```html
<div class="controls">
    <td>
        <label class="checkbox inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="illness[]" value="cbx_aids">
            Aids
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label class="checkbox inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="illness[]" value="cbx_anemia">
            Anemia
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label class="checkbox inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="illness[]" value="cbx_arthritis">
            Arthritis
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label class="checkbox inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="illness[]" value="cbx_Artificial">
            Artificial Joints
        </label>
    </td>
</div>
```

```php
public function illNess(Request $request)
    {
        $illness_arr = $request->illness; // returns an array
        if(count($illness_arr) > 0) {
            $new_record = new Illness();
            $new_record->column_name = json_encode($new_record); // pushes as an array into the column of the table
            $new_record->save(); // saves the record into the table
        }
    }
```

Comment: how do i save it in my database sir @RashedRahat?

Comment: In what format or style do you want to save? I mean lets say you have two values of `illness`. Now these two values will be stored in database as two rows? Or in one single row?

Comment: in one single row. I think as an array

Comment: I have updated my solution according to your query. It will satisfy your query. Have a look please. Hopefully, it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

your inputs don't have 'name' attribute

for example:

```
<label class="checkbox inline">
   <input type="checkbox" name="cbx_aids" value="1">
     Aids
</label>
```

And in your controller:

```
if($request->has('cbx_aids')){
    ...
}
```

Comment: sorry about that already updated my code above.. My other problem is this illness checkbox has 50 checkbox. I need my system to check for checked checklist then put it in an array to implode it into a string so that i can output all previously checked values

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misinterpreted your question but according to my understanding, you want values of all the checked checkboxes. For that, you should give value of name attribute like this to all checkboxes of the same group:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="illness[]" value="cbx_aids">
```

**illness[]**

And in the Controller you can loop through all the values :

```
foreach ($request['illness'] as $value) { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I still have a question. how to store it in my database? and what input type?

Answer (score 0):

I usually make a boolean checkbox adding a jQuery like this:

```
<td>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
        <input id="checkboxId" type="checkbox" name="illness[]" >
        Aids
    </label>
</td>

<script>
    $('#checkboxId').on('change', function(){
        this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
        //alert(this.value);
    }).change();
</script>
```

Then your request will receive checked input as value 1 and not checked as 0, so you can filter them easily.

Comment: what should i put in my controller so that i can store it in my database?